# Which was the first doctor, M.D. or Ph.D.?

Tags: etymology

For which title was the term "doctor" first given?  Was it originally meant for the medical doctor, or for just anyone holding a doctoral degree?

Also:  When did the later usage become common, and why?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

***Doctor*** is a Latin word, and it was borrowed from Latin already formed, with a meaning, namely *'teacher'*. The word is formed exactly the way *teacher* is:

- a verb root (English *teach-*, Latin *doc-*), plus
- an agentive suffix (English *-er*, Latin *-tor*).

*Doctor* was in use for many centuries before there were universities, or degrees. It was used to refer to an especially learned person, one who was authorized and qualified to teach a particular subject. Which might be medicine, philosophy, theology, law, logic, history, etc.

It wasn't until the Twelfth Century AD in Europe that the modern Western universities were invented. The first universities were Guilds, of Masters or Students, and the Masters were Doctors, i.e, authorized teachers. Gradually the Bachelor's, Master's, and Doctor's degrees evolved from a guild structure of Apprentice, Journeyman, and Master.

For details, consult Haskins' classic *[The Renaissance of the Twelfth Century](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Renaissance_of_the_12th_century)*

Comment: Thank you for the interesting information.  Could you elaborate on how "doctor" came into common use to particularly describe medical practitioners?

Comment: But which of Ph.D. or M.D. was first referred to as a doctor? Are you saying that at the year such degree titles/letters started to be conferred, those people were already referred to as 'doctor'? And if so, then the answer boils down to which of PhD or MD was the first to be conferred?

Comment: That depends entirely on what you want to mean by "PhD", "MD", and "degree", all of which are much later inventions than _Doctor_. And all of which vary a great deal from place to place and period to period. There is no single answer because there is no single question.

Comment: I think he's saying that "Doctor" referred to any learned person of any subject at that time. Therefore, both their equivalents of medical doctors and doctors of philosopy were referred to as doctors starting around the same time.

Comment: Yeah, that'll do. Certainly there's no way to solve the status war between Medical Doctors and other Doctors. Let'em fight it out.

Comment: +1, makes sense since doctor is often the one teaching you about how to take care of your body.

Comment: An editorial in *Wall Stret Journal* (["Are Physicians Really Doctors"](http://www.design.caltech.edu/erik/Misc/real_doctors.html), 1995) gives some history and argues that medical doctors adopted the title "doctor" from academics.

Comment: The medical _Dr._ is a modern conflation of several medieval roles: the healer or leech, and the surgeon or barber. Both medicine and surgery are taught to modern American MDs, though there is still considerable difference between the practices.

Answer (score 4):

As noted in etymonline and in previous answer, the word *[doctor](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=doctor)* has been in use in English since ca. 1300.  Regarding the abbreviations you ask about, etymonline says:

- *[M.D.](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=M.D.&allowed_in_frame=0)*, "1755, abbreviation of Latin *Medicinæ Doctor* "doctor of medicine."
- *[Ph.D](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=Ph.D&allowed_in_frame=0)*, "attested from 1869; abbreviation of L. *Philosophiae Doctor* 'Doctor of Philosophy.'"

The abbreviations *D.D.* or similar for *Doctor of Divinity* and *L.L.D.* for *Legum Doctor* or *Doctor of Laws* are somewhat older than *M.D.* or *Ph.D.*.  For example, the 21st edition of Nathan Bailey's ***An universal etymological English dictionary***, printed in 1675, shows *[T.D.](http://books.google.com/books?id=CFBGAAAAYAAJ&pg=PT842&lpg=PT842&dq=etymology+Doctor+of+Divinity&source=bl&ots=hkWDVBGiqv&sig=iJKLwzRrytGL4_g_4IpZGC9FMo8&hl=en&sa=X&ei=WcIxT7qrHcGviALzt9mZCg&ved=0CLMBEOgBMA0#v=onepage&q&f=false)* in the entry after fifth *SYZYGIA* entry, and shows *L.L.D.* after *LIZEN'D*.  [image: Bailey's, T.D. and L.L.D.]

The answer to "Which of Ph.D. or M.D. was first referred to as a doctor?" is that neither was first, as both *D.D.* and *L.L.D.* are earlier.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that doctor for both PhD and MD came about the same time: late 14c ... slowly besteading the OE word for a physician: leech.

From Etymology Online:

> doctor (n.) c.1300, "Church father", from O.Fr. doctour, from M.L.
>   doctor "religious teacher, adviser, scholar", in classical L.
>   "teacher", agent noun from docere "to show, teach, cause to know",
>   originally "make to appear right," causative of decere "be seemly,
>   fitting" (see decent). Meaning "holder of highest degree in
>   university" is first found late 14c.; as is that of "medical
>   professional" (**replacing native leech**), though this was not common
>   till late 16c. The transitional stage is exemplified in Chaucer’s
>   *Doctor of phesike* (Latin physica came to be used extensively in M.L.
>   for medicina). Similar usage of the equivalent of doctor is colloquial
>   in most European languages ...

In OE and ME, a doctor was a *leech* (lǣce in OE) which gave us many other words:
leechbook — book of prescriptions
leechcraft — art of healing; medicament, remedy, prescription
leechcraftig (leechcrafty) — skilled in medicine
leechchest — medicine chest
leechdom — medicament, medicine; salvation
leechdomlic — salutary, beneficial, health-giving
leechdomness — cataplasm, poultice
leechfee — doctor's fee
leechfinger — fourth finger
leechhouse — sick room, hospital
leechiren — surgeon's knife, lancet
leechsalve — medicinal ointment
leechseax — lancet
leechwyrt (leechwort) — medicinal herb, drug

Answer (score -3):

The word doctor originally came from the word docket.
It has a lot to do with maritime law, when a ship 
Entered a canal it was just like giving birth.
Once a ship exit the canal it is given a docket number like a mother is given a birth certificate with a number.
The doctor “docket “ received the baby from the mothers birth canal “water” just like a ship.
Research Maritime law.

Comment: https://www.etymonline.com/word/doctor

Comment: It is derived from the Latin verb "docere" (to show, teach) which in Italian became "docente" (teacher)